# Branch IO deep link parameter not appearing in react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, deep-linking, branch.io

I have implemented branch in my react native app.  All links in the platform are setup and I am seeing the parameter I need in the URL.  The problem I am having is when the app first installs the value is null.  It's only after I have installed then go back to the link it recognizes this parameter.  Is this the intended behavior?

How I have my branch call setup in an initial load component.  I added this to a componentDidMount() since I'm using redux and wanted to alert redux of the value.

```
componentDidMount(){
    branch.subscribe(({params, uri, error}) => {
      if (params && !error) {

        if(params.coid != null){

          const id = params.coid
          this.showAlertMessage(
            'BUNDLE COMPANY ID',
            id
          )
          this.props.CheckAdmin(id)
          LocalStore.get('localID').then(localID => {
            LocalStore.save('localID', {value: id});
          })
        }
      }else{

        this.showAlertMessage(
          'BUNDLE COMPANY ID',
          "BUNDLE COID IS NULL"
        )
        this.props.IsMasterDownload()
      }
      this.showAlertMessage(
        'BRANCH URI',
        uri
      )
    })

  }
```

Does branch.subscribe need to live outside of my component class in order to function properly?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for bringing this up. I'm the current maintainer of that repo, and I've been making some changes there that should make things a little clearer.

TL;DR:

- Update to 2.0.0-beta.5 or later. The behavior of these arguments changed slightly to be more consistent.
- Don't use the `uri` argument, which is deprecated and will eventually be removed.
- Look for the `+non_branch_link` parameter instead for non-Branch links.
- Use the data in the `params` with Branch links.
- For Branch links, `uri` is the same as `params['~referring_link']`.
- The callback is invoked any time the API responds, including things like initialization, in which case `params` will just contain `{ "+clicked_branch_link": false, "+is_first_session": false }`.
- See the [Branch docs](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/configuring-links/guide/) for details on the contents of `params`.
- See the examples in the repo, particularly [webview_example](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/react-native-branch-deep-linking/blob/master/examples/webview_example/src/App.js#L13).
- `componentWillMount` is a good place to call `branch.subscribe`.

This SDK always had a slightly different data model from all of Branch's other SDKs, for one reason or another. No other SDK provides a `uri` parameter. All relevant information is present in the `params` and `error` arguments, which are also returned by other SDKs (e.g., iOS, Android, Cordova). Previously the RN SDK would not pass the `params` if the `~id` parameter was not present. The `~id` parameter is assigned by Branch to identify each unique click on a Branch link. In particular, it is not present for non-Branch links. So in many cases the `subscribe` callback was called with null `params`. The `uri` parameter was added only in order to provide the `+non_branch_link` for non-Branch links, since the `params` were filtered out. These differences made it harder to support, added unnecessary code complexity and caused confusion among developers. [It has been changed](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/react-native-branch-deep-linking/pull/203) in 2.0.0-beta.5. The `uri` parameter should now be considered deprecated. Its behavior should be unchanged except in some odd edge cases. You always need to consult the `params` unless `error` is non-null.

See the [Branch docs](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/configuring-links/guide/) for information on all Branch parameters.

When opening a non-Branch link, the only interesting parameter that is returned is `+non_branch_link`, which is just the non-Branch URL. This is the same as the `uri` parameter for these links.

The `subscribe` callback is invoked whenever the API responds to the SDK, which includes things like initialization, for deferred deep linking. When no link is available at launch, you are still called back. But `+clicked_branch_link` is false and `+non_branch_link` is absent. This is consistent with the behavior of the rest of Branch's SDKs.

I've spent a lot of time recently on the [examples](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/react-native-branch-deep-linking/tree/master/examples) in the repo. They all work. In particular, the [webview_example](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/react-native-branch-deep-linking/blob/master/examples/webview_example) illustrates a realistic app integration with link routing. I'd urge you to have a look at how that works. In particular, you set a number of parameters when you call [createBranchUniversalObject](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/react-native-branch-deep-linking/blob/master/examples/webview_example/src/Article.js#L34) and [showShareSheet](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/react-native-branch-deep-linking/blob/master/examples/webview_example/src/Article.js#L34) (or getShortUrl). They are passed back to [subscribe](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/react-native-branch-deep-linking/blob/master/examples/webview_example/src/App.js#L24) and used to route the link in the app and show a view with the appropriate content.

At the moment, everything works and is consistent with Branch's data model elsewhere.

I think there is still room for improvement. In particular, it would be nice to be able more easily to distinguish a link open from a successful initialization response. I think it would be an improvement to add methods to the SDK and adopt an API like the RN Linking module, e.g. `branch.getInitialLink()`, `branch.addEventListener('open', ({params}) => { ... })`, `branch.addEventListener('init', () => { ... })`, `branch.addEventListener('error', ({error}) => { ... })`. That will probably happen in a later release like 2.1.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy and sorry for a slow reply.  I will try changing my call to inside componentWillMount and gettng rid of uri.  I was not even using that as I just needed the params for a key value. Also realized I had not added my SHA256 Cert Fingerprints to Enable App Links.  Would that also cause this to not function correctly?  Cheers.

Comment: Another question Jimmy,  When adding two parameters what is the best way to split them in params.  I've noticed if I pass two like ?coid=XYZ?l=ABC The params.coid = XYZ?l=ABC

Comment: Beyond the specifics of this SDK, my knowledge is hit and miss. You should consult the Branch docs at https://dev.branch.io or integrations@branch.io for details. I'm not sure how the SHA fingerprint works with App Links, but it seems unlikely that it would work sometimes and not others. I'd recommend using metadata for your params when building links in the app or the Dashboard. If the params are entirely contextual and can't be included in the link metadata, I think you can use the usual URL query parameter syntax: ?coid=XYZ&l=ABC (&, not ?).

Comment: Just an FYI the & did work and I am now getting both parameters in the link.  Thanks again for the help!